# Get equivalent native JavaScript for this JQuery animate(scrollLeft) function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm looking for the following jQuery `animate()` function for native (vanilla) JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#btn-menu-nav-previous').click(function() {
            $(".menu-inner-box").animate({scrollLeft: "-=100px"});
        });
        
        $('#btn-menu-nav-next').click(function() {
            $(".menu-inner-box").animate({scrollLeft: "+=100px"});
        });
    });
</script>
```

This code could normally allow to paginate menu list when clicking on **next** and **previous**.

But I'm searching its equivalent in pure JS without using JQuery.

Here is what I did:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var menu = document.querySelector(".menu-inner-box");
  var prev = document.getElementById("btn-menu-nav-previous");
  var next = document.getElementById("btn-menu-nav-next");
  prev.addEventListener("click", function() {
    menu.animate([{
      scrollLeft: menu.scrollLeft
    }, {
      scrollLeft: menu.scrollLeft - 100
    }], {
      duration: 500,
      fill: "forwards"
    });
  });
  next.addEventListener("click", function() {
    menu.animate([{
      scrollLeft: menu.scrollLeft
    }, {
      scrollLeft: menu.scrollLeft + 100
    }], {
      duration: 500,
      fill: "forwards"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
nav#menu-container {
  background: #586e75;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 56px;
}

#btn-menu-nav-previous {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 9px 12px;
  background: #8f9a9d;
  fill: #FFF;
}

#btn-menu-nav-next {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 9px 12px;
  background: #8f9a9d;
  fill: #FFF;
}

.menu-inner-box {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 54px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-item {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 57px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: no-wrap;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.last-item {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu-container" class="arrow">
  <div id="btn-menu-nav-previous" style="fill: #FFF">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M15.41 7.41L14 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L10.83 12z" />
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div id="btn-menu-nav-next">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z" />
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-inner-box">
    <div class="menu">
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 1</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 3</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 4</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 5</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 6</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 7</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 8</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 9</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 10</a>
      <a class="menu-item last-item" href="#">Menu 11</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

But it doesn't work at all.

Can anyone give me any help please ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple alternative would be to use the native [`scrollBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy) method.

I supports a `behavior` parameter for smooth scrolling:

```
el.scrollBy({
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Drawback: you can't change the transition speed.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var menu = document.querySelector(".menu-inner-box");
  var prev = document.getElementById("btn-menu-nav-previous");
  var next = document.getElementById("btn-menu-nav-next");
  prev.addEventListener("click", function() {
    menu.scrollBy({
      left: -100,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  });
  next.addEventListener("click", function() {
    menu.scrollBy({
      left: 100,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
nav#menu-container {
  background: #586e75;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 56px;
}

#btn-menu-nav-previous {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 9px 12px;
  background: #8f9a9d;
  fill: #FFF;
}

#btn-menu-nav-next {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 9px 12px;
  background: #8f9a9d;
  fill: #FFF;
}

.menu-inner-box {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 54px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-item {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 57px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: no-wrap;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.last-item {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu-container" class="arrow">
  <div id="btn-menu-nav-previous" style="fill: #FFF">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M15.41 7.41L14 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L10.83 12z" />
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div id="btn-menu-nav-next">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z" />
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-inner-box">
    <div class="menu">
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 1</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 3</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 4</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 5</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 6</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 7</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 8</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 9</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 10</a>
      <a class="menu-item last-item" href="#">Menu 11</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```